# What is the expected time for the first of these bulbs to burn out?

Tags: probability-distributions

A company buys 100 lightbulbs, each of which has an exponential lifetime of
1000 hours. What is the expected time for the first of these bulbs to burn
out? 
For this, I divided 1000/100 to get 10 hours, is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: use that if $X_i\sim$ Exp$(\lambda_i)$ then $\min X_i\sim$ Exp$(\sum\lambda_i)$

You can google the proof, for example [here](http://www.math.wm.edu/~leemis/chart/UDR/PDFs/ExponentialM.pdf) or [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#Distribution_of_the_minimum_of_exponential_random_variables)

Then you have $\lambda_i=\frac{1}{1000}$, $\sum\lambda_i=\frac{1}{10}$, and the expected lifetime of the first burnt bulb is 10 hours. So your answer is correct.

Comment: How did the 1/1000 go to 1/10?

Comment: $E[X_i]=\frac{1}{\lambda_i}=1000$, so $\lambda_i=\frac{1}{1000}$.

Then $\min X_i
\sim$ Exp$(\lambda)$, with $\lambda=\lambda_1+...+\lambda_{100}=\frac{100}{1000}=\frac{1}{10}$.

Lastly, $E[\min X_i]=\frac{1}{\lambda}=\frac{1}{1/10}=10$